# Can't show an image in slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to make a slider with several pics. so I'm using react. first I create Main component, where I put as a child Slider component. in Slider component where I created an array with an object, object has a path to the picture.  then I create SliderContent component and import it in Slider component. then I created Slide component and import it in SliderContent component.
here it is how looks Main component code:

```
import Slider from "../Components/Slider";



export default function Main(){

    return(
        <>
            <div className="main">
                <Slider />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

here is how looks component Slider code:

```
import './Slider.css'
import SliderContent from "./SliderContent";
// import Slide from "./Slide";

const images = [
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "imageTwo",
        img: "../images/pharma.jpg"
    }
]

export default function Slider(){



    return(
        <>
            <div className="slider">
                <SliderContent slides ={images} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

here is how looks component SliderContent code:

```
import './Slider.css'
import Slide from "./Slide";


export default function SliderContent(props){
    return(
        <>
            <div className="sliderContent">
                {
                    props.slides.map(slide =>
                        <Slide key={slide.img} content={slide.img} />
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

and here is how looks Slide component code:

```
import './Slider.css'

export default function Slide(props){
    return(
        <>
            <div className="slide" >
                <img alt="pic" src={props.content}/>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

but here is what it shows:
[it shows an alt atribute of img tag in Slide component and picture doesn't open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMEvS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to require() your local images in order for them to show in React components, [due to how Webpack bundles your app](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images).

```
<img src={require('../images/pharma.jpg')} />
```

Another option would be to directly import the image:

```
import MyImage from '../images/pharma.jpg';
```

and then just use it where you need it:

```
<img src={MyImage} />
```

Comment: sincerely thank you Yulian. I don't have webp[ack config.js file in my project., should I create it myself, or it would be added after i download file-loader library? thank you in advance

Comment: React handles bundling on its own so you don't really need to mess with custom configs like that unless you encounter specific use cases which require it. Simply importing local images using require() or "import" will work by default.